# Textbox inside a gridview and its value not reflecting on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a textbox column in gridview where that column was filled with a predefined database value but some of the cells have a null value assigned. I have to update those cells only but when I used, it appears a null string in `Textbox1`.

I have also bind grid on `if(!ispostback)` in page `load()` but got same result.
What I am missing here?

```
TextBox TextBox1 = row.FindControl("txt1") as TextBox;
```

Comment: Please provide your backend code as well. How do you  call the database, store procedured or function etc.